# How to list all files in folder then select multiple files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, multiple-select

I would like to be able to:

1. Put my .bat script in some folder with files and run it
2. In CMD, script should list all files in that folder with select-able numbers
3. In user prompt, user should be able to choose two or more files for further processing, by entering their numbers separated by commas, spaces or whatever

Below is what I have so far. It can choose one file only.
I am not developer, this was copy/pasted/edited and cannot figure out how to enhance it to work with multiple files.
The final goal is to have names of chosen files in .txt file, one name per new line

Many thanks in advance.

```
echo off
:START
cls
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
:
:: Read in files
for %%x in (*.*) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)

:
echo.
echo Please choose file by number:
echo.

:
:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
)
echo.

:
:: Retrieve User input
set /p select=?: 
echo.

echo !choice[%select%]! > my-choice.txt

echo  TYPE ANY KEY TO GO BACK IN START MENU ...
pause  >NUL
goto START
```

Comment: Use another `FOR` command to iterate the choices.  If you enter `1,3` at the select prompt, you can then iterate through those choices with the `FOR` command like so: `FOR %%G IN (%select%) do echo !choice[%%G]!`

Comment: Thank you very much, if you make this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it :)

```
echo off
:START
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
:: Read in files
for %%x in (*.*) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
echo.
echo Please choose files by number:
echo.
:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x] !choice[%%x]!
)
echo.
:: Retrieve User input
set /P selected="select file numbers: "
for %%i in (%selected%) do (
    echo !choice[%%i]! >> my-choice.txt
)    
echo.
echo  TYPE ANY KEY TO GO BACK IN START MENU ...
pause  >NUL
goto START
```

Please note that this does not check for valid numbers or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally suggest this methodology for the task, you've laid out.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

:Menu
ClS
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('(Set File[^) 2^> NUL') Do Set "%%G="
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=[]" %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %__AppDir__%where.exe ".":"*" 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe /N /V ""') Do Set "File[%%G]=%%~nxH" & Echo %%G. %%~nxH
If Not Defined File[1] GoTo :EOF

:Select
Set "#="
Set /P "#=Choose a file from the list by entering its item number. "
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('(Set File[%#%]^) 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%find.exe "="') Do Set "File[#]=%%H"
If Not Defined File[#] GoTo Select

:Main
(Echo %File[#]%) 1> "my-choice.txt"
Echo Press any key to go back to the menu. . .
Pause 1> NUL
GoTo :Menu
```

This could obviously be simplified for the task you're performing, but, I'm going to assume that you've dumbed down the task for the purposes of your question.

***[EDIT /]***

*Please note, that this does ensure the end user can only input valid information. Also it does not use delayed expansion at all, so unlike in your example, files named using `!` characters will not be problematic.*